# OpenCV, distrubution project files without library's installation

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opencv, distribution

How to build an application that uses OpenCV library without the need to install it (whole library) on the client computer? I mean the possibility to put only the required library files in the application directory. My question is connected with using Qt developer software on Linux OS.
How to setup .pro file for forcing searching library files (by developed application) in local directory instead of searching them in system opencv installed localization.

Any help is greatly appreciated and expected
Artik

Comment: you can build static libs for opencv, so your executable is one big chunk with (hopefully) no further dependancies (no idea about qt, though)

Comment: unfortunately, my use of  QT license excludes the possibility of static linking:(

Comment: ... excludes the possibility of static linking of the *Qt* libs... (that does not cover opencv)